# How can I prevent webpack from moving URL encoded font into a file

Tags: reactjs, webpack, create-react-app

I am using Create react app (CRA) and craco.
I am also using a 3rd party component that loads a custom font as base64 encoded string.

```
src:url(data:application/x-font-ttf;charset=utf-8;base64,AAEA...AAAAA==) format("truetype")}.
```

When building the application, this load becomes:

```
src:url(/static/media/1653a5f7) format("truetype")}
```

oddly enough, the newly generated file has no name nor extension. I am removing the leading dot it had using  the following craco command (leading dot was making linux completely ignore the file and return 404)

```
config.output.assetModuleFilename = 'static/media/[name][hash:8][ext]';
```

When releasing said file to my Linux server, it does not load the font (even though file is loaded with status 200)
In a pre-craco version everything did work fine, I have a second environment where the same font is loaded, and it is indeed loaded as inline url instead of extracted.
I have tried the following craco code to no results:

```
...
style: {
    postcss: {
      plugins: [
        postcssUrl({
          url: 'inline',
          maxSize: 5000000 
        }),
      ],
    },
  }
...
```

```
...
 webpack: {
    configure: (config) => {
      config.module.rules.forEach((rule) => {
        if (rule.oneOf instanceof Array) {
          const urlLoader = rule.oneOf.find(
            (loader) => loader.loader && loader.loader.includes('url-loader')
          );
          if (urlLoader) {
            urlLoader.options = { limit: false };
          }
        }
      });
    return config;
    },
  },
...
```

```
...
const cssRule = rule.oneOf.find(
            (loader) => loader.test && loader.test.toString() === '/\\.css$/'
          );
          if (cssRule) {
            cssRule.use = [
              'style-loader',
              {
                loader: 'css-loader',
                options: {
                  importLoaders: 1,
                  modules: true,
                },
              },
              {
                loader: 'postcss-loader',
                options: {
                  postcssOptions: {
                    plugins: [
                      postcssUrl({
                        url: 'inline',
                      }),
                    ],
                  },
                },
              },
            ];
          }
...
```

At this point I'm shooting in the dark. Is there a way to prevent inline base64 encoded URLs from being extracted to separate files?

For reference, here is my full craco.config file

```
module.exports = {
  webpack: {
    configure: (config) => {
      config.module.rules.forEach((rule) => {
        if (rule.oneOf instanceof Array) {
          const urlLoader = rule.oneOf.find(
            (loader) => loader.loader && loader.loader.includes('url-loader')
          );
          if (urlLoader) {
            urlLoader.options.name = 'static/media/[name][hash:8].[ext]';
          }
          // Retain the exclude property
          rule.oneOf[rule.oneOf.length - 1].exclude = [
            /\.(js|mjs|jsx|cjs|ts|tsx)$/,
            /\.html$/,
            /\.json$/
          ];
        }
      });

      // Custom function for media file name generation
      config.output.filename = 'static/js/[name][contenthash:8].js';
      config.output.assetModuleFilename = 'static/media/[name][hash:8][ext]';
      config.output.chunkFilename = 'static/js/[name][contenthash:8].chunk.js';
      return config;
    },
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I had an issue with the craco file, my exclude was missing the following parameter:

```
/^$/
```

Not completely certain why not having an empty string regex matcher would cause this, but everything works when added.
Full file below:

```
module.exports = {
  webpack: {
    configure: (config) => {
      config.module.rules.forEach((rule) => {
        if (rule.oneOf instanceof Array) {
          rule.oneOf[rule.oneOf.length - 1].exclude = [
            /^$/, 
            /\.(js|mjs|jsx|cjs|ts|tsx)$/,
            /\.html$/,
            /\.json$/
          ];
        }
      });
      return config;
    },
  }
};
```